# Links are not working on scrolling images

Tags: jquery, html, image, hyperlink

My website (http://amosjackson.com/index) has scroll navigation where you click on navigation links and it scrolls to the place in the webpage.

When I implemented this, the links for images stopped working.

They did not disappear because when I hover over the images, I still see the links and I can right click and open the link, but when I just click on them, nothing happens.

My html is not brilliant so please make any criticism constructive. Since it's a work in progress, you have to do /index or it redirects to a building page.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @AmosJa! *Your code works for me in Chrome.* strike that.  I thought you meant the original navigation.  Now I see what you mean.

Comment: It works in the latest firefox

Comment: i'm not talking about the navigation. the images (the blue one and the green one). the links do not work.

Comment: I just realized that @AmosJa ;-)  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in the jQuery script you are using for the slider.

Seems you are preventing every link from firing with this piece of code.

```
$("a").bind("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

Try targeting only nav links, something like

```
$("#nav a").bind("click",function(event)
```

Comment: one other thing... how do I get reputation?

Comment: Pleasure @AmosJa! Here is a link that explains how rep works: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation.  Again, welcome to SO!